# Matrix to DF transpose R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a matrix which I am transposing to a data frame. When I do so the first column doesnt have a name . How do I name it. Below is the matrix and the transposed df.

```
Metric_name   May 2017 Jun 2017 Jul 2017 Aug 2017 Sep 2017
[1,] "nike"   "12"     "38"     "41"     "34"     "45"    
[2,] "adidas" "643"    "673"    "585"    "580"    "662"   
[3,] "UA"     "442"    "502"    "634"    "667"    "804"   
[4,] "Puma"   "1145"   "1218"   "1342"   "1329"   "1273"
```

**code**:

```
dj1<- as.data.frame(t(dj()))
dj2<- dj1() %>% set_names(unlist(.[1,])) %>% tail(-1)
```

**Output df :**

```
              nike adidas   UA    Puma
May 2017      12    643    442   1145
Jun 2017      38    673    502   1218
Jul 2017      41    585    634   1342
Aug 2017      34    580    667   1329
Sep 2017      45    662    804   1273
```

Comment: Try with `tibble::rownames_to_column(df, 'date')`

Comment: Thank you @akrun.